# Procedure to submit iPhone application to App Store?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Is it necessary to pay $99 before I can watch the video to submit an iPhone application to the App Store, or it is available free of cost anywhere?

Comment: the question should be "Is it necessary to pay $99 before I can watch the video to submit an iPhone application to the App Store?"

Answer (score 12):

You can join the developer program and watch the video without paying. It's on Video → App Store and Distribution after you've logged in:

- https://developer.apple.com/videos/app-store-and-distribution/

You may also read:

- https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/

What you can't do without putting down your $99 is get your application on an iPhone or iPod touch (and that includes your own).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the $99 fee to register as an iPhone developer?

Even if you can find a copy of the video, you would still have to pay the fee in order to get your application hosted on the App Store. Apple keeps a fairly tight handle on all of this stuff, so they require all developers to register if they want to sell software in the App Store. Apple will also have the final say on wether or not your software can be sold.

Bottom line: if you intend to sell software through the App Store, you will have to pay Apple the $99 fee.

Answer (score -1):

$99 is for registration for the developer where you can debug your iphone application on your mobile when you are developing as we had done tone of iphone application though business account and that is more than $99 but it will help you more once you register with $99 - thanks

Comment: The difference between the business account and the single-developer ($99) account is the number of devices that can run the application without going through the App Store.