# what are the Steps for uploading iPhone application to apple store...?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Procedure to submit iPhone application to App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308290/procedure-to-submit-iphone-application-to-app-store)

what are the Steps for uploading iPhone application to apple store...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Itunes Connect
 Add AppId -> OwnParts
Provisioning
 Distribution ->New Profile->App Store->Profile Name->AppId->[ Submit ]

Download Profile

Organizer
 Provision Profile

Info.plist
 Bundle Identifier (from AppId - > Configure)

Project 
 Info
  Configuration
   (Add New) Distribution

Remove entitlement.plist from code signing

Copy -> Product -> App File

Zip - > App File

Itunes Connect -> Manage Your application

Also Download Application Loader

Answer (score 2):

There's a detailed Developer Guide on app submission available from the iTunes Connect web site (login required).  There's also an article titled Prepare for App Submission on the front page of the iOS Dev Center, and a Program Users Guide in the Provisioning Portal.

Read them all carefully.

Very carefully.

If you break all the steps down from scratch there are on the order of 100.  Miss one detail and you likely fail.  (A couple years ago it was not uncommon for an entire corporate development team to be stuck for weeks because they skipped one tiny step.)