# Submit an IOS application to apple store

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Procedure to submit iPhone application to App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308290/procedure-to-submit-iphone-application-to-app-store)

Its my first IOS application and i would like to submit it to the apple store.

My clients give me his account ( a user name and a password). The steps i want to do are :

1. create and generate a certificate with the identity of mu client. it's ok.
2. create an app Id. i can create it in the portal.What is the value of the app id, what should app id in the portal matches in xcode ?
3. create a distribution provisioning profile. it's ok
4. sign the app with this new provisioning profile. Can you help me please for this step ?? thanks.
5. compile and build the app for distribute it in the apple store. How i can do this please ?
6. I would like to forward the binary to my client, should i zip the binary ?
7. How i will test that the binary is correct ( i mean that i can submit it the apple store)?
8. Should i submit my app via itunes connect in zip format ?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below links for your reference.

[Steps to upload an iPhone application to the AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796482/steps-to-upload-an-iphone-application-to-the-appstore)

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/04/04/list-guideline-for-submitting-iphone-application-to-apple-store/

Cheers.