# App Submission on Apple's App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Procedure to submit iPhone application to App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308290/procedure-to-submit-iphone-application-to-app-store)

I know this question would have been asked before for many times but I couldn't find any step-by-step guide which can help me like a starter. My app is about to launch. Please tell me some good places where I can find a good step-by-step procedure on **How to submit app on Apple's App Store** ?

Regards
Akshay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [iOS Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/my/distribution/index.action). The links in the *"Distribution"* section expand to step-by-step guides, complete with screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step guide with pictures:

http://www.cannonballbounce.com/content/sumbitting-your-iphone-game-app-store