# Submit Universal apps to the apple app store?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Procedure to submit iPhone application to App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308290/procedure-to-submit-iphone-application-to-app-store)

How to submit Universal apps to the apple app store

Answer (score 2):

You can find a complete description of the required steps on [Apple's development portal](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html).

Look for the heading "Creating a Universal Application".  Hope this helps.